# Issue with spaces while writing the string to csv file

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xj7f.jpg)I am writing list of Strings to a csv file using java. While writing the data to file, spaces are getting removed. How to preserve spaces in the string. Please find the code as below:

```
    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String fileName = "D:/appFiles/stoTest.csv";
        FileWriter fstream = null;
        PrintWriter writer = null;

        List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
        test.add("1226207   20220506    0113279 78.00   C");
        test.add("1226207   20220506    0113285 242.31  C");
        test.add("1226207   20220506    0113281 52.00   C");
        test.add("1226207   20220506    0113280 75.00   C");

        try {
            // Create file
            fstream = new FileWriter(fileName);
            writer = new PrintWriter(fstream);
            
            for (String s : test) {
                writer.println(s);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally  {
            // Close the output stream
            if (writer != null) {
                writer.close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you sure you are viewing the file correctly? Does the same happen if you view it in a text editor?

Comment: Text Editor is working fine. I am having this issue only when exporting to csv file. I just ran and I uploaded the output image of csv file, I got now. Can you please check.

Comment: Check in text editor

Comment: Try viewing the CSV file in notepad. Excel changes a lot of formatting when opening CSV files

Comment: If viewing in a text editor works fine, then there is no issue to be solved. It is some excel setting, which is not the scope of stackoverflow

Comment: Text Editor and note pad works fine. But my requirement is to export into csv file.

Comment: csv is a format which you can view in every basic text edit, or excel. however, excel can show it wrong, while the data is still correct. so dont rely on excel to show it correctly. if notepad shows correct, you are fine

Comment: @MADI If the spaces show up in the file when viewed in a text editor then the spaces are in the file. How *other* programs (e.g., Excel) choose to *interpret* that file is a separate issue.

Comment: @MADI It's not clear why spaces would matter at all here: spaces are being used to (a) separate the data, and (b) make things line up nice for humans. Excel does not care about humans. The spaces are not necessary for correct interpretation of the data. AFAICT the code, and Excel, are doing the right things.